# json_encode with danish character getting null value in php

Tags: php

I'm using danish character with json_encode. But its getting null value.

```
$response = array("Logind gennemført", "Din konto venter på aktivering");
print_r($response);
echo json_encode($response, true);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code is fine, what does your error log file say? And what character encoding is your script in?

Comment: U need to encode with utf8 and in json_encode u don't need second param true.

Comment: @tom-chadaravicius its encode not decode :p

Comment: @devpro Pardon and thank you. Been a long day :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode array values as utf8 so you can use `utf8_encode()` and `array_map`.

```
$yourArr = array_map('utf8_encode', $response); 

$json = json_encode($yourArr);
```

Note that you are using two params in [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

- Make sure the script you create the array is UTF-8 encoded, or convert the array to UTF-8.
- When using in HTML, make sure the character set is set to UTF-8.

Sample code:

```
<?php
    // Page header, specify character set
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
';

    // Code
    $response = array("Logind gennemført", "Din konto venter på aktivering");
    print_r($response);
    echo json_encode($response, true);

    // Page footer
    echo '</body>
</html>
';

?>
```

Result:

Print array:

`Array ( 
      [0] => Logind gennemført 
      [1] => Din konto venter på aktivering 
  )`

Echo json object string:

`["Logind gennemf\u00f8rt","Din konto venter p\u00e5 aktivering"]`